# Trouble installing m2crypto with pip on OS X / macOS

Tags: macos, pip, macos-sierra, osx-elcapitan, m2crypto

```
pip install m2crypto
```

Generates the following output:

```
building 'M2Crypto.__m2crypto' extension
swigging SWIG/_m2crypto.i to SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c
swig -python -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/openssl -includeall -modern -o SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c SWIG/_m2crypto.i
SWIG/_m2crypto.i:30: Error: Unable to find 'openssl/opensslv.h'
SWIG/_m2crypto.i:33: Error: Unable to find 'openssl/safestack.h'
SWIG/_evp.i:12: Error: Unable to find 'openssl/opensslconf.h'
SWIG/_ec.i:7: Error: Unable to find 'openssl/opensslconf.h'
error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
```

I've run:

```
brew install swig
```

Answer (score 179, accepted):

I wanted a nicer way without installing manually and using only Homebrew (which also does not link openssl by default). Also using `pip` was a requirement. This seems to work with newest m2crypto 0.22.5. I also tested it once with m2crypto 0.22.3 and seems also to work. The OpenSSL version here is 1.0.2d:

```
brew install openssl
brew install swig
```

Finally install m2crypto on macOS in your **Bash**. It is a long command but it changes SWIG and clang environment variables only during `pip install` so that m2crypto will get all OpenSSL requirements:

```
env LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" \
CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" \
SWIG_FEATURES="-cpperraswarn -includeall -I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" \
pip install m2crypto
```

btw. the last command also works if you use e.g. a requirements.txt.

Update:
Additional also the command for **fish shell** users...

```
env LDFLAGS="-L"(brew --prefix openssl)"/lib" \
CFLAGS="-I"(brew --prefix openssl)"/include" \
SWIG_FEATURES="-cpperraswarn -includeall -I"(brew --prefix openssl)"/include" \
pip install m2crypto
```

Comment: +1 Really like this method, I could use it with a recursive dependency install script, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: woked like a charm :-)

Answer (score 11):

thanks to therealmarv env flags i was able to get this to work with the macports version of openssl/swig, this is what i did:

```
sudo port install openssl
sudo port install swig
sudo port install swig-python
```

then use therealmarv lines but replace "$(brew --prefix openssl)" with the dir from macports which should be "/opt/local"

```
sudo env LDFLAGS="-L/opt/local/lib" \
CFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include" \
SWIG_FEATURES="-cpperraswarn -includeall -I/opt/local/include" \
pip install M2Crypto
```

Answer (score 5):

I just went through a lot of pain getting this working in El Capitan.  Here is what I had to do:

**Install OpenSSL (you have to use an older version, m2crypto will not compile otherwise)**

```
curl -O https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-0.9.8zg.tar.gz
tar -xvzf openssl-0.9.8zg.tar.gz
cd openssl-0.9.8zg
./Configure --prefix=/usr/local darwin64-x86_64-cc
make && make test
sudo make install
```

**Install m2crypto**

```
git clone https://github.com/martinpaljak/M2Crypto.git    
cd M2Crypto
python setup.py build build_ext --openssl=/usr/local
sudo python setup.py install build_ext --openssl=/usr/local
```

AFAIK it is installed... I still have to do some testing though.

Comment: Also, this repo seems to be more active: https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto.git

I think I'll try installing this version as well.

Comment: I was able to use hjjiang answer from above with OpenSSL 1.0.2e

Comment: `python setup.py build build_ext --openssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl`


`sudo python setup.py install build_ext --openssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl`

works for me

Answer (score 4):

Got exact [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33005354/9994168) on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, while trying to execute

```
pip install M2Crypto==0.24.0
```

Did the following to get rid of it:

```
sudo apt-get install swig
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my problem (Python 2.7):

```sh
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Answer (score 0):

macos    v10.15.6
m2crypto v0.35.6
pip      v20

Solution by therealmarv works,
If the program does not take effect, you can try to upgrade your brew packages. Before the solution.

```
brew update              # update homebrew self
brew upgrade             # upgrade all
```

Answer (score -11):

sudo apt-get install python-m2crypto

Comment: The question is tagged as `osx-elcapitan`, where `apt-get` most likely is not available.