# Why can't I install m2crypto in pipenv on OSX?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pipenv

Anyone know what I could be doing wrong. I'm trying to switch from pip3 to pipenv I keep getting this error on osx when trying to install uwsgi and m2crpyot: https://pastebin.com/FZZUpcwa

```
pipenv install -r requirements2.txt
Requirements file provided! Importing into Pipfile…
Pipfile.lock (6adb91) out of date, updating to (10e36a)…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Updated Pipfile.lock (10e36a)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (10e36a)…
An error occurred while installing https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/-/archive/0.27.0/m2crypto-0.27.0.zip#egg=4dd1b7f! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing lxml==3.6.1! Will try again.
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 95/95 — 00:03:30
An error occurred while installing uwsgi==2.0.14! Will try again.
Installing initially–failed dependencies…
Collecting 4dd1b7f from https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/-/archive/0.27.0/m2crypto-0.27.0.zip#egg=4dd1b7f
Installing collected packages: 4dd1b7f

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/timo/.local/share/virtualenvs/jm-web-G18c0xlX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 228, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/timo/.local/share/virtualenvs/jm-web-G18c0xlX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
  File "/Users/timo/.local/share/virtualenvs/jm-web-G18c0xlX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 49, in install_given_reqs
    **kwargs
  File "/Users/timo/.local/share/virtualenvs/jm-web-G18c0xlX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 748, in install
    use_user_site=use_user_site, pycompile=pycompile,
  File "/Users/timo/.local/share/virtualenvs/jm-web-G18c0xlX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 961, in move_wheel_files
    warn_script_location=warn_script_location,
  File "/Users/timo/.local/share/virtualenvs/jm-web-G18c0xlX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/wheel.py", line 316, in move_wheel_files
    assert info_dir, "%s .dist-info directory not found" % req
AssertionError: 4dd1b7f .dist-info directory not found

  ☤  ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/3 — 00:00:00
```

and I've run into similar issues before with pip on mac that I could fix
is the previous fixes I used when using pip: https://yoirtuts.com/index.php?title=M2Crypto_Issue_Mac_OSX and https://yoirtuts.com/index.php?title=Compile_Issue_With_UWSGI_On_OSX

I've tried doing this in docker, outside docker just with plain pipenv. I don't know what I could be doing wrong. It seems the issue is with m2crypto. In the past I had to install m2crypto with pip like this:(when using plain pip3 and virtualenv on OSX:

```
pip3 install m2crypto --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" --global-option="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

and with uwsgi I also would run into issues occasionally that I could solve with:(in a virtualenv using pip3 )

```
CFLAGS="-Wno-error=varargs" pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Just an update to question:

I've tried installing m2crypto in a docker container without using a requirements.txt and using a Pipfile instead. So in other words using this command to install from Pipfile:(So this is in the dockerfile for installing the dependencies when the image is built)

```
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy
```

This is what I put in my Pipfile for m2crypto

```
m2crypto = "==0.27.0"
```

This is the error that I keep getting:

```
    copying M2Crypto/BN.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/M2Crypto
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/cb.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/ssl_dispatcher.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/timeout.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/SSLServer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/Cipher.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/TwistedProtocolWrapper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/Context.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/Session.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/Connection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/M2Crypto/SSL
    copying M2Crypto/SSL/Checker.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/M2Crypto/SSL
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_ext
    building 'M2Crypto._m2crypto' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/SWIG
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -I/tmp/pip-install-qdabh1md/m2crypto/SWIG -c SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.o -DTHREADING
 -Wno-deprecated-declarations
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c: In function ‘_wrap__STACK_num_set’:
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:9493:19: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct stack_st’
       if (arg1) (arg1)->num = arg2;
                       ^~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c: In function ‘_wrap_new__STACK’:
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:9720:48: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct stack_st’
       result = (struct stack_st *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct stack_st));
                                                    ^~~~~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:9723:1: warning: label ‘fail’ defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
     fail:
     ^~~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c: In function ‘_wrap_sk_new_null’:
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:9866:1: warning: label ‘fail’ defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
     fail:
     ^~~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c: In function ‘_wrap_sk_deep_copy’:
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:9951:40: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘OPENSSL_sk_deep_copy’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
       result = (_STACK *)sk_deep_copy(arg1,arg2,arg3);
                                            ^~~~
    In file included from /usr/include/openssl/crypto.h:28:0,
                     from /usr/include/openssl/bio.h:20,
                     from /usr/include/openssl/err.h:21,
                     from SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:3557:
    /usr/include/openssl/stack.h:32:16: note: expected ‘OPENSSL_sk_copyfunc {aka void * (*)(const void *)}’ but argument is of type ‘void * (*)(void *)’
     OPENSSL_STACK *OPENSSL_sk_deep_copy(const OPENSSL_STACK *, OPENSSL_sk_copyfunc c, OPENSSL_sk_freefunc f);
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c: In function ‘_wrap_stack_st_OPENSSL_STRING_stack_set’:
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:10354:19: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct stack_st_OPENSSL_STRING’
       if (arg1) (arg1)->stack = *arg2;
                       ^~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:10354:29: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘OPENSSL_STACK {aka struct stack_st}’
       if (arg1) (arg1)->stack = *arg2;
                                 ^~~~~
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c: In function ‘_wrap_new_stack_st_OPENSSL_STRING’:
    SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c:10386:63: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct stack_st_OPENSSL_STRING’
       result = (struct stack_st_OPENSSL_STRING *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct stack_st_OPENSSL_STRING));
```

Comment: Did you try it on virtualenv?

Comment: Yeah I did try in virtualenv. This works perfectly in virtualenv:``` pip3 install m2crypto --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" --global-option="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"``` but I'm trying to move my project to pipenv , which I'm starting to think is a bad idea.

Comment: Well, don't you need to say `pipenv install m2crypto` then to use it with pipenv? I have never used so I am not sure. But I saw the usage, and you install the packages like this. I feel like you are trying to install this library to OS X directly (not via virtualenv or pipenv).

Comment: pipenv creates a virtualenv to install the libraries into from what I understand

Comment: Yes, it does. But when you start with `pip install ...` then it goes to current activated environment. Therefore I thought pipenv is a wrapper around everything therefore you have to use its name.

Comment: I need to make this process repeatable. I don't want to only install them on my machine, I also need to get it working with pipenv in the ci environment and in docker.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I tried this in docker aswell I keep getting this error: http://dpaste.com/1HPV86C

Comment: I was using m2crypto version 0.27.0 , but I also tried other versions. Here are some unsolved threads with same issue: https://community.home-assistant.io/t/upgrade-m2crypto-error/31517/2 and https://pagure.io/fm-orchestrator/issue/700

Answer (score 5):

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005354/trouble-installing-m2crypto-with-pip-on-os-x-macos) I was able to install it with the following command:

```
env LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib" CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" SWIG_FEATURES="-cpperraswarn -includeall -I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" pipenv install M2Crypto
```